# Object array as char array in a linked list -- are my assumptions about alignment valid?

Tags: c++, alignment

I'm writing a slice allocator in **C++98**. The allocator will consist of two template classes:

1. Low-level allocator class which would allocate the actual memory,
2. High-level allocator class which will wrap requested objects as `char[]` arrays of appropriate length.

I would like to know whether the assumptions I make below about alignment are valid.

---

First of all, I assume that within an array of objects (of type `T`), each object is properly aligned. I don't see anything specific about that in the standard but it seems like a reasonable assumption to me.

Considering that, if I take `sizeof(T[n])`, the returned size should contain any padding necessary and thus be suitable for storing the array `T[n]`.

---

Secondly, *18.4.1.1* (`operator new`) states:

> 1 **Effects:** The *allocation function* (3.7.3.1) called by a *new-expression* (5.3.4) to allocate *`size`* bytes of storage suitably aligned to represent any object of that size.

Thus, I assume that `::operator new(sizeof(T[n]))` should create a memory block suitably aligned for the array `T[n]`.

---

Finally, *9.2* (*class members*) states:

> 17 A pointer to a POD-struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [*Note:* There might therefore be unnamed padding within a POD-struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. ]

Thus, I would assume that in a `struct` like:

```
struct node
{
    char data[sizeof(T[n])];
    node* next;
};
```

allocated via `new node`, the `data` member will be properly aligned for the array `T[n]`.

---

Are the above assumptions correct or am I missing something? I believe that I have to implement the linked list manually since the C++ standard doesn't give any guarantees about node member order.

Comment: Don't use array-new. Call `::operator new` directly and have only raw memory.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ai, I didn't even notice it was there. You are completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumptions are correct. I may have missed something but I don't get why you can't have something like this:

```
struct node
{
   T[n];
   node* next;
};
```

Comment: I would like to use the same storage for different objects of the same size. Thus, I have to cast them into some common type.

Comment: @Michał Górny: in such case I'd strongly object about using char array. Nothing guarantee that objects of the same size will be preserved as such across various compilers or even compilers version. You stuck with pointer to char anyway.

Comment: I think I don't understand what are you referring to, exactly.

Comment: I mean that nothing guaranties that if objects of types T1 and T2 have same sizes, then they still will have same sizes on different compiler version. Padding rules are not fixed or standardized in any way.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. If size changes, the object will simply go into pool for another size.